# Is it possible to use multithreading in multiprocessing with python?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I try to applicate multithreading in multiprocessing with Python.

Question 1: Is this even possible?

Question 2: Is it really worth it to perform better?

For this I tried to implement following example script but i only got the initial number "999" in my database in the end. What mistake did I do?

Best thanks in advance! I appreciate it so much!

```
from threading import Thread
import os
import time

from multiprocessing import Process

#from queue import Quene
from multiprocessing import Queue

def start_multiprocessing(q, db):    
    processes = []
    num_processes = os.cpu_count()
    # create processes
    for i in range(num_processes):
        p = Process(target=start_threading, args=(q, db))
        processes.append(p)
    #start
    for p in processes:
        p.start()
    # join
    for p in processes:
        p.join()

def start_threading(q, db):
    threads = []
    num_threads = 10
    # create processes
    for i in range(num_threads):
        t = Thread(target=square_numbers, args=(q, db))
        threads.append(t)
    #start
    for t in threads:
        t.start()
    # join
    for t in threads:
        t.join()

def square_numbers(q, db):
    value = q.get()
    db.append(value)
    time.sleep(0.5)


# main:

db = [999]
q = Queue()
for i in range(1, 21):
    q.put(i)

start_multiprocessing(q, db)

print(db)
```

Comment: Please focus on one answer. Do you want to know whether it is possible, what is the benefit, or which error you made? See the [ask] page for details how to ask an on-topic question and how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: Yes, it is possible.

Question 2: Whether it is worth or not depends on what you are trying to do. You need to consider that multithreading in Python is limited by the [GIL](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock). You do get proper concurrency when using multipprocessing.

In your example I think the issue comes from using a normal list that it is passed between processes. That list is not shared between processes. At the end of the execution the initial list in the main process won't have changed as you are effectively creating a copy in each process and appending to the copies. I think you want to use a [Manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#managers).